# Where is Breeze Cache Memory located

Tags: breeze

I dont understand how Breeze.EntityManager store the data? It stores it in local container called entity cache, but where is this stored? Is it local storage, session storage and is there any limit on entity data that can be stored?

Answer (score 0):

The `EntityManager` cache is a private, in-memory data structure within an instance of the `EntityManager` itself.

There is no public API for touching it. The physical limit is the memory in your browser. The practical limit is less of course.

The `EntityManager` cache is ***transient***. It has the lifetime of the `EntityManager` instance. Close the browser and kiss it good bye.